# Spring MVC app not found after tomcat deploy on subfodler

Tags: spring-mvc

This is my web xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml,
            classpath:spring-security.xml
            classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/assets/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/favicon.ico</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>LocalePicker.Locales</param-name>
            <param-value>fr</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/view/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/view/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>



</web-app>
```

On a local machine all works fine. If I get

http://localhost

web app works.

When I deploy on a remote server the uri is

http://localhost/myapp

application not found

How can I solve this without changing server configuration?

Comment: on remote server how can you call localhost ?

Comment: http://serverip/myapp

Comment: i use server ip but problem is that application works only as root application and not in the subfolder . I think that i need to tell spring that application is under subfolder

Comment: inside a jsp i solve using c:url tag. the problem persiste inside spring security config where i set default login redirect and other options.

Answer (score 0):

First check your application is deployed properly or not. You can check it on tomcat. After deploying if it is not started may be there is some jar file issue.